# how to integrate Other Ads network on codename one app

Tags: codenameone, ads

I want to know if i can implement other ad networks like adcolony in my codename one app using the adservice/ads component or any other method. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate the ad provider in a similar way to the flurry, admob interstitial ads etc.

See samples here: https://www.codenameone.com/cn1libs.html

And the 3rd party library integration tutorial here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html

There is a more up to date version of that tutorial in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,it really gave me direction. One problem though, i discovered I need to add hints to the android manifest.Please how do I do that in codename one

Comment: I saw instructions like

Comment: Next, copy and paste the following three activity definitions just before the end application tag near the bottom:

<activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

<activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

Comment: Use build hints for that: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html e.g. android.xapplication can inject into the manifest at the bottom as described here.

Comment: I just followed the instructions, but on building I see this error

Comment: /tmp/build8407058777144396115xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/myaddImpl.java:2: error: package com.jirbo.adcolony does not exist
import com.jirbo.adcolony.*;
^
/tmp/build8407058777144396115xxx/MyApplication/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/myaddImpl.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        AdColony.configure(this,"version:2.1,store:google","appbbd19fddafa443dbb7","Ad Zone #1");

Comment: How did you add the jar/aar file? Did you place it under the native/android directory?

Comment: Yes sir. I did that

Comment: What files did you place under the native/android directory? What build hints? Can you link to the adcolony setup instructions?